# safari и svg как маска для DIV

Tags: svg, safari

Создаются 4 почти одинаковых по содержанию блока с заданными масками через инлайн свг, находящемся в пределах тела страницы. Хотелось бы уточнить у сведущих людей, почему через -webkit- префикс обработка данных блоков происходит нормально во всех поддерживающих данный префикс браузерах, кроме мобильного сафари? что я упускаю?

CSS:

```
           .underline {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            hr.white-hr {
                border-top: 1px solid #fff;
                width: 100%;
            }

            hr.blue-hr {
                border-top: 1px solid #1976D2;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .uppercase {
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            #prices {
                margin-top: 0;
                padding-top: 5%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #prices .prices {
                width: 24.5%;
                margin: 0 0.25%;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
            }

            #prices .filter {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(13, 71, 161, .25);
                background-repeat: repeat;
                background-size: 375px;
                z-index: 100;
                opacity: .25;
            }

            #prices .circle-with-border {
                z-index: 50;
                height: 180px;
                width: 180px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 3px solid #1976D2;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #prices .circle-with-border img {
                z-index: 50;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #prices .old_price {
                z-index: 50;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                text-decoration: line-through;
                margin: 10px auto;
            }

            #prices .discount {
                z-index: 50;
                font-size: 1.5em;
                margin: 10px auto;
            }

            #prices .cards .cards-action {
                z-index: 50;
                padding: 0;
                border-top: none;
            }

            #prices .cards .cards-action a:not(.btn):not(.btn-large):not(.btn-floating) {
                z-index: 50;
                margin-right: 0;
                width: 50%;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 15px 0;
                line-height: normal;
                float: left;
            }

            #prices .header {
                z-index: 50;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }

            #prices .more {
                z-index: 50;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                margin: 0;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                line-height: normal;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
            }

            #prices .to_form {
                z-index: 50;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                margin: 0;
                margin-left: 10px;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: normal;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #ffb74d;
            }

    /* svg masking */
            #first_clipper_s,
            #first_clipper_m,
            #first_clipper_l,
            #second_clipper_s,
            #second_clipper_m,
            #second_clipper_l {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                transform-origin: 0;
            }

            @media all and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 600px) {
                #prices {
                    clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
            padding-bottom: 7.5%;
                }
                #prices .cards {
                    clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
            width: 100%;
                }
            }

            @media all and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
                #prices {
                    clip-path: url(#secondClip_m);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#secondClip_m);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#secondClip_m);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#secondClip_m);
            padding-bottom: 7.5%;
                }
                #prices .cards {
                    clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
            width: 48%;
            margin: 0 1%;
                }
            }

            @media all and (min-width: 992px) {
                #prices {
                    clip-path: url(#secondClip_l);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#secondClip_l);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#secondClip_l);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#secondClip_l);
            padding-bottom: 7.5%;
                }
                #prices .cards:nth-of-type(1),
                #prices .cards:nth-of-type(3) {
                    clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                    min-height: 500px;
                }
                #prices .cards:nth-of-type(2),
                #prices .cards:nth-of-type(4) {
                    clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -webkit-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -moz-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    -o-clip-path: url(#secondClip_s);
                    min-height: 500px;
                }
            }
```

html:

```
    <!-- container with cards -->
    <div id="prices" class="grey">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 info">
            <h1 class="uppercase arvoBold white-text"> Blah-blah-blah</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container container-wide">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m3 l3 prices cards z-depth-0 blue-grey darken-1 flex-column">
            <p class="uppercase arvoBold white-text header">
              Very very very interesing header </p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="circle circle-with-border flex-row"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
            <p class="clearReg grey-text text-lighten-1 old_price">
              some strike-thru text</p>
            <p class="arvoBold amber-text text-lighten-2 discount">
              alternative text</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="cards-action">
              <a href="#how_it_works">
                <p class="white-text clearReg more">more</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#extended_form">
                <p class="amber-text text-lighten-1 clearReg to_form">action</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m3 l3 prices cards z-depth-0 blue-grey darken-2 flex-column">
            <p class="uppercase arvoBold white-text header">
              another interesting text</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="circle circle-with-border flex-row">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
            <p class="clearReg grey-text text-lighten-1 old_price">
              another strike text</p>
            <p class="arvoBold amber-text text-lighten-2 discount">
              another alternative</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="cards-action">
              <a href="#how_it_works">
                <p class="white-text clearReg more">more</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#extended_form">
                <p class="amber-text text-lighten-1 clearReg to_form">action</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m3 l3 prices cards z-depth-0 blue-grey darken-3 flex-column">
            <p class="uppercase arvoBold white-text header">
              one more interesting text</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="circle circle-with-border flex-row">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
            <p class="clearReg grey-text text-lighten-1 old_price">
              one more strike text</p>
            <p class="arvoBold amber-text text-lighten-2 discount">
              one more alternative</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="cards-action">
              <a href="#how_it_works">
                <p class="white-text clearReg more">more</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#extended_form">
                <p class="amber-text text-lighten-1 clearReg to_form">text</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m3 l3 prices cards z-depth-0 blue-grey darken-4 flex-column">
            <p class="uppercase arvoBold white-text header">
              last one interesting header</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="circle circle-with-border flex-row">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="responsive-img">
            </div>
            <p class="clearReg grey-text text-lighten-1 old_price">
              last strike text</p>
            <p class="arvoBold amber-text text-lighten-2 discount">
              last alternative text</p>
            <hr class="blue-hr">
            <div class="cards-action">
              <a href="#how_it_works">
                <p class="white-text clearReg more">more</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#extended_form">
                <p class="amber-text text-lighten-1 clearReg to_form">action</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- svg masks -->
    <svg id="first_clipper_l">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="firstClip_l" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.15 0.85,0 0,0.15 0,0.85 0.15,1 1,0.85" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    <!-- tablet-->
    <svg id="first_clipper_m">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="firstClip_m" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.1 0.9,0 0,0.1 0,0.9 0.1,1 1,0.9" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    <!-- mobile-->
    <svg id="first_clipper_s">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="firstClip_s" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.025 0.975,0 0,0.025 0,0.975 0.025,1 1,0.975" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>

    <svg id="second_clipper_l">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="secondClip_l" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.15 0.15,0 0,0.15 0,0.85 0.85,1 1,0.85" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    <!-- tablet-->
    <svg id="second_clipper_m">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="secondClip_m" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.1 0.1,0 0,0.1 0,0.9 0.9,1 1,0.9" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    <!-- mobile-->
    <svg id="second_clipper_s">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="secondClip_s" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <polygon points="1,0.025 0.025,0 0,0.025 0,0.975 0.975,1 1,0.975" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

[Демо тут](http://codepen.io/spirit-infernal/full/xEWqvb/)

Comment: попробуйте -apple- || -khtml- префиксы

Comment: -apple-clip-path / -khtml-clip-path ?

Comment: или же Add xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" для вашего svg тега

Comment: -apple- / -khtml- результата не принесли. всё также, отображается первый блок, последующие три скрыты, хотя в хтмл разметке присутствуют.
попробую с xmlns

Comment: еще одно уточнение, проблема только с частью создаваемой страницы, другие блоки, выше и ниже этой части с ссылками на те же самые свг файлы отображаются корректно. могут быть проблемы с ксс селекторами, которые используются для указания масок?
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg " ...> результата не принесло

Comment: version="1.1" забыли указать, возможно clip-path версия сафари не поддерживает или  же придется искать костыли как можно по другому запулить

Comment: <svg baseProfile="tiny"
     version="1.2"
     viewBox="0 0 4298 2826"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> или этот

Comment: мне кажется, вьюбокс тут не нужен. пробую с разными версиями, но кажется удалось в анголязычном сегменте СО найти след на возможное решение проблемы

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372435/clipping-path-in-svg-not-working-in-safari, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574099/what-could-make-safari-skip-clip-path-and-mask-with-svg, http://greensock.com/forums/topic/13760-svg-clip-issue-with-ios-safari-firefox/

Comment: я вот на это наткнулся:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468314/svg-clippath-to-clip-a-div-doesnt-work-in-safari-when-i-duplicate-it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079044/css-enabling-webkit-hardware-acceleration-works-fine-in-safari-messes-up-in-ch/31079763#31079763

и да, (-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px) / -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0)) это помогло, но не совсем так, как нужно - блоки сжались в полоски 1px высотой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы следует указать и самому inline svg контейнеру и clip-path внутри него свойство transform: translateZ(0) !important;
через !important для избежания возможной перезаписи другими селекторами ксс.
пример [кодепен](http://codepen.io/spirit-infernal/pen/xEWqvb)

```css
 /* свойства для свг контейнера  */ 
        #first_clipper_s {
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateZ(0) !important;
  }
    /* свойства для блока, на который накладывается свг  */
  @media all and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 600px) {
        #prices #card1  {      
        mask: url(#firstClip_s);
    clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);        
    -apple-: url(#firstClip_s);    
    -khtml-: url(#firstClip_s);
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
    -moz-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
    -o-clip-path: url(#firstClip_s);
                width: 100%;
                transform: translateZ(0) !important;        
   } 
          ...
        }
```

```html
<!-- svg контейнер -->
<svg id="first_clipper_s">
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="firstClip_s" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="1,0.025 0.975,0 0,0.025 0,0.975 0.025,1 1,0.975" />
   </clipPath>
   <mask id="firstClip_s" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="1,0.025 0.975,0 0,0.025 0,0.975 0.025,1 1,0.975" />
   </mask>
  </defs>
 </svg>

<!-- блок на который накладывается свг для обрезки по контурам -->
      <div id="card1" class="prices cards z-depth-0 blue-grey darken-1 col s12 m3 l3 flex-column">
        <p class="uppercase arvoBold white-text header">
          Very very very interesing header </p>
        <hr class="blue-hr">
        <div class="circle circle-with-border flex-row"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
        <p class="clearReg grey-text text-lighten-1 old_price">
          some strike-thru text</p>
        <p class="arvoBold amber-text text-lighten-2 discount">
          alternative text</p>
        <hr class="blue-hr">
        <div class="cards-action">
          <a href="#how_it_works">
            <p class="white-text clearReg more">more</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#extended_form">
            <p class="amber-text text-lighten-1 clearReg to_form">action</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

css:
```